# checkbox htmlentities() expects parameter 1 to be string, array given

Tags: php

I'm using htmlentities() in a controller:

```php
foreach ($_POST as $key => $value) {
    $_POST[$key] = htmlentities($value);
}
```

I have a table with a checkbox, and I want to delete multiple items using checkbox but I get this error:

> htmlentities() expects parameter 1 to be string, array given.

posting the form gives this data:

```
array(3) { 
    ["submit-button"]=> string(0) "" 
    ["records"]=> NULL 
    [1]=> string(1) "1" 
}
```

When I remove the above code, posting the form gives this data:

```
array(3) { 
    ["submit-button"]=> string(0) "" 
    ["records"]=> array(2) { 
        [0]=> string(1) "1" 
        [1]=> string(1) "3" } 
    [1]=> string(1) "1" 
}
```

So htmlentities can't read records as array.
What can I do?

Comment: Same as you do with `$_POST` check `is_array($value)` and loop it.

Comment: please could give me syntax

Comment: foreach ($_POST as $key => $value) {
        if (is_array($value)) {
          foreach ($value as $key => $val) {
            $_POST[$key] = htmlentities($val);
          }
        }
        else {
          $_POST[$key] = htmlentities($value);
        }
      }

Comment: is this correct?